# Could we get more options added to "This question belongs on another SE site"

Tags: feature-request

If you vote to close a question because it is off topic at Network Engineering SE, but on topic elsewhere, there isn't really a built in consistent way of indicating where that question should have gone.

[image]
[image]

What are the chances we can get ServerFault and Stackoverflow added as options instead of just Meta? Those are the most common overlap stack exchanges we get.

I feel its more helpful to say "This is off topic here, but on topic *there*" than it is to simply say "this is off topic here".

Comment: Isn't this the same as http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/477/additional-closed-reason-not-enough-details?

Comment: @RonMaupin Not really. I'm hoping to add more options of where we can vote to move a question. Not modify the current close *reasons*.

Comment: Right, but in Mike's answer, it shows what others are doing.

Comment: Also keep in mind that just because a question is about a topic that is covered by another site, this doesn't make it a question that should be migrated.  SE prefers that you only migrate questions that don't stand a high chance of being closed on the other site, so for example if it is too broad and off topic here, it shouldn't be migrated. Also, users should make sure that they understand what is on topic on the other site, not just think it is on topic.

Comment: if I recall, when you choose that option, it then gives you a "it belongs here..." field -- or at least, it does for moderators. If I specify where it belongs, it just moves it over. For non-mod users, this sort of like custom close reasons I asked about long ago. SE just seems to like to leave us typing the same comments over and over and over and over and over

Comment: Unlike custom close reasons, moderators don't have access to modify this list (or at least I have never found a means of doing so).